# How to recognise where each compilation unit in a "c++ -E" output

Tags: c++, compilation, header, preprocessor

In order to understand more about compilation i tried to go into the compilation process step by step ?
I created the files `Foo.hpp` , `Foo.cpp` and `Bar.cpp` 
`Foo.hpp` : contains a simple class interface.
`Foo.cpp` : contains it's implementation (includes `Foo.hpp`) 
`Bar.cpp` : contains entry point `main()` which simply construct Foo class (includes `Foo.hpp`)

I compiled with `C++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -E Foo.cpp Bar.cpp` 
and was expecting a separate compilation unit for `Foo.cpp` and `Bar.cpp` but i got only one single output to `stdout`, well i read somewhere that the compiler actually receives separate compilation unit for each .cpp file so i assumed the output is just a simplification ?
 **QUESTION 1.0 :** is this a correct assumption ?? 
This is the output of preprocessor :

```
# 1 "Bar.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 414 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "Bar.cpp" 2


# 1 "./Foo.hpp" 1


class Foo {
 private:
  int _value;
 public:
  Foo( int value);
  int getValue( void ) const;
};
# 4 "Bar.cpp" 2

int main( void ) {
 Foo foo(2);
 foo.getValue();

}
# 1 "Foo.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 414 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "Foo.cpp" 2
# 1 "./Foo.hpp" 1


class Foo {
 private:
  int _value;
 public:
  Foo( int value);
  int getValue( void ) const;
};
# 2 "Foo.cpp" 2


Foo::Foo( int value) : _value(value) {};
int Foo::getValue( void ) const { return this->_value ; };
```

**QUESTION 1.1:** Assuming that this is just a simplified version and the compiler actually receives separate compilation units, How can i differentiate where a specific CU is? is it the `# "number" "filename"` lines that separates them ??

**QUESTION 1.2:**  if yes then note that in `# 4 "./Bar.cpp" 2` section (Bar.cpp includes `Foo.hpp`) the content of the header are actually copied in `Bar.cpp` section while not copied in `Foo.cpp` section (`Foo.cpp` also include `Foo.hpp`) why is that ? 
**QUESTION 1.3:** last off-context question : what are these creatures `<built-in>` `<command line>` .

**EDIT**:

as @HolyBlackCat mentioned in the comments, I need actually to compile each separately to get a separate compilation unit for each , so if you encountered the same confusion, Just compiler your files separately.

Comment: Your question can only be answered in your compiler's documentation. Whatever C++ compiler you are using, you'll need to check its documentation for information on this.

Comment: How didn't actually specify how you're calling your compiler.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat just added

Comment: Process .cpp files separately and use `-o filename` to specify the output filename for each. And `-I./Foo.hpp` is pointless since `-I` sets an include search *directory*.

Comment: Yes now headers are copied in both files .

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate compialtion units then don't specify all source files on the command line. Compile them one by one:

```
C++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -E -o Foo.e Foo.cpp
C++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -E -o Bar.e Bar.cpp
```